# Mocha doesn't recognize dynamic imports

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, babeljs

I'm using Mocha to test a react/webpack/babel application that is written in es6 stage-0 syntax, which includes [dynamic imports](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import). Webpack compiles it without errors, but mocha throws the following error when reaching a dynamic import syntax:

```
import('path/to/file').then(...)  
^^^^^^  
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

The command that i'm running is:

```
$ mocha --compilers js:babel-register src/**/*.test.js
```

And in my `.babelrc` I have to following:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"]
}
```

Comment: It is not Mocha's job to "recognize dynamic imports". Mocha runs in Node and **Node** does not have native support for imports (dynamic or static). Babel has to convert them to something that Node can consume. I know from experience that a properly configured Babel has no issue converting static imports. I don't know how it handles dynamic ones though. I don't see anything in [Node's documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) that is a straightforward native Node equivalent to a dynamic import.

Comment: @Louis but if i'm using babel as a compiler (with a stage-0 preset), shouldn't it handle it properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @louis has mentioned, this is a node issue. The solution is to add the [dynamic-import-node](https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node) plugin to babel:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"],
  "plugins": ["dynamic-import-node"]
}
```

Which will add support for the `import(...)` syntax in node.

Comment: The `syntax-` plugin is for if you want to parse `import()` but _not_ transform it. Using it alongside a plugin like `dynamic-import-node` is a no-op. You should remove it.

Comment: @loganfsmyth using any of the above plugins without the other causes node to throw said error. Any idea why? Any better solution?

Comment: You need `dynamic-import-node` but not `syntax-dynamic-import`. The `dynamic-import-node` plugin [includes `syntax-dynamic-import` inside itself.](https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node/blob/master/src/index.js#L1)

Comment: @loganfsmyth yes you're right, not sure why it wasn't working without it previously. Answer updated.